# How to get Running total in SQL when values are not same?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get the running total for Week (like Show as 'Running Total in' in Excel Pivot table.

I have tried with the below query.

```
select A.*,
(SELECT SUM(b.value)
            FROM Tbl_Running_Total_Test B
            WHERE   B.Fweek <= A.Fweek
                    AND A.level1=B.level1
                    AND A.level2=B.level2
                    AND A.level3=B.level3
                    AND A.level4=B.level4
            )
 from Tbl_Running_Total_Test A
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle: [SQl Fiddle Sample table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/471b2d/2)

If I use the above query I am not getting the expected result. [image: Below is Expected and results with my try]

Answer (score 2):

Your level3 & level4 have extra characters, so that's why it's not adding up:

```
(4,'1QAB','2XMN','3YOPq','4ZGHi',25),
(4,'1QAc','2XMo','3YOqr','4ZGij',74),
(4,'1QAd','2XMp','3YOrs','4ZGjk',86),
(4,'1QAe','2XMq','3YOst','4ZGkl',97);
```

The others are like this:

```
(3,'1QAB','2XMN','3YOP','4ZGH',40),
(3,'1QAc','2XMo','3YOq','4ZGi',60),
(3,'1QAd','2XMp','3YOr','4ZGj',80),
(3,'1QAe','2XMq','3YOs','4ZGk',120),
```

Comment: Agreed, Is there anyway to get the desired result when looking out the values for level1 or Level2

Comment: @Punith Well that depends on your requirement. Strip away the last characters, don't match the level at all...